# Twitter bootstrap fixing viewing area of a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I am building a dashboard with rails 4 and twitter bootstrap. My show.html.erb looks like this:

```
 <% if @store_entries %>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>  
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>E</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%@store_entries.each do |value| %>
                <tr> 
                    <td><%= value['A']%></td>
                    <td><%= value['B']%></td>
                    <td><%= value['C']%></td>
                    <td><%= value['D']%></td>
                    <td><%= value['E']%></td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<% else%>
    <p>No entires to display</p>
<% end%>
```

The problem I am facing is: Content of each value is quite long and as a result the table doesn't fit horizontally on my browser window. I would like the table to fit into my browser window so a user doesn't have to scroll horizontally. I am new to both bootstrap and rails.

Comment: Ok. I was able to solve this by using the follwing css: `.mycontainer {
overflow: auto;
}
` Nested the table inside div tag with mycontainer class.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or capturing a screenshot ? I would be very helpful

Comment: @Vdt Thanks. solved it! See update

Answer (score 0):

Please put your table in div element and give the max width to the div

Example:

```
<div style="width:400px;">
   your table content
</div>
```